# Is it a good practice to use an "untouchable"? It cant be instanized, nor inherited

Tags: php

lets imagine a class, for checking values:

```
final class Validator
{
    private function __construct() { }
    private function __clone() { }

    public static final function checkValue ($a)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static final function checkValueInDb ($a)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

its useless to instantize it, or inherit - no need to mock, or use dependency injections. However, right now I cant test __constructor and __clone because they are private, and code coverage says its not 100%

Comment: I think that is overengineering.

Comment: You forgot `private function __wakeup() { }` : )

Answer (score 1):

You could use abstract class with static methods instead of this construction with private methods.

Comment: abstract function can still be inherited, I dont want it. Sadly there is no "final abstract" :)